# Running scrapyd and scrapyrt next to each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, scrapy, amazon-ecs

I want to set up a large scale **scraping** service. At the moment I use the *scrapyrt* api (https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#) but I would like to run my spiders *asynchronously* so my crawls can scale up. I heard that *scrapyd* was the tool of choice for that, however, I would still like to be able to use *scrapyrt* for debugging purpose. Is it possible to have scrapyd and scrapyrt running next to each other in the same Docker container and have them callable with their own API.

Also when deploying scrapyd on ecs, I would like to have my scrapyd project deployed on each ecs instance I am using instead of having to deploy them manually with `scrapyd-client` everyt time a new instance is created.  Is it something that is easily doable with *scrapyd*.

Cheers